# A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table Data stream write

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, pyspark-schema

I am having `.option("mergeSchema", "true")` in my code still I am getting schema mismatch error.  I am reading schema for parquet my timestamp was in `bigint` format so I converted to timestamp format and then created new column date which I want to partition my data on.

```
df = df.withColumn("_processed_delta_timestamp", F.current_timestamp()) \
  .withColumn("_input_file_name", F.input_file_name())\
  .withColumn('date', F.date_format(F.date_trunc('Day', (F.col("timestamp") / 1000).cast(TimestampType())), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) \
  .withColumn('date', to_date(F.col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

```
df.writeStream.format('delta') \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_path) \
  .partitionBy('date')\
  .option('path', output_path)\
  .toTable(f"{output_database_name}.{output_table_name}")
```

Error that I am getting

```
To enable schema migration using DataFrameWriter or DataStreamWriter, please set:
'.option("mergeSchema", "true")'.
For other operations, set the session configuration
spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled to "true". See the documentation
specific to the operation for details.

Table schema:
root
-- metric_stream_name: string (nullable = true)
-- account_id: string (nullable = true)
-- region: string (nullable = true)
-- namespace: string (nullable = true)
-- metric_name: string (nullable = true)
-- dimension: struct (nullable = true)
    |-- ApiName: string (nullable = true)
-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
-- value: struct (nullable = true)
    |-- max: double (nullable = true)
    |-- min: double (nullable = true)
    |-- sum: double (nullable = true)
    |-- count: double (nullable = true)
-- unit: string (nullable = true)
-- _processed_delta_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- _input_file_name: string (nullable = true)


Data schema:
root
-- metric_stream_name: string (nullable = true)
-- account_id: string (nullable = true)
-- region: string (nullable = true)
-- namespace: string (nullable = true)
-- metric_name: string (nullable = true)
-- dimension: struct (nullable = true)
    |-- ApiName: string (nullable = true)
-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
-- value: struct (nullable = true)
    |-- max: double (nullable = true)
    |-- min: double (nullable = true)
    |-- sum: double (nullable = true)
    |-- count: double (nullable = true)
-- unit: string (nullable = true)
-- _processed_delta_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
-- _input_file_name: string (nullable = true)
-- date: date (nullable = true)

         
Partition columns do not match the partition columns of the table.
Given: [`date`]
Table: [`timestamp`]
```